# Tensor contraction in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I have a tensor `weights` of shape `(?,4)` and a tensor `embeddings` of shape `(?,4,1024)`.

I would like to contract the tensor by taking a weighted mean of the 4 tensors in each row of `embeddings` according to the corresponding `weights`, finally producing a tensor `output` of shape `(?,1024)`.

How can I do that? I tried with `output = tf.tensordot(weights, embeddings, axes = [1,1])` but that produced a tensor of shape `(?,?,1024)` instead.

Comment: May I ask what have you ended up using? Thanks!

Comment: @LucaCappelletti I used `tf.einsum`. See a sample of the code [in this repo](https://github.com/ctlearn-project/ctlearn/blob/attention/ctlearn/default_models/attention.py) (line 80)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

weights = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 4])
embeddings = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 4, 1024])
output = tf.einsum('ij,ijk->ik', weights, embeddings)
```

You can express the same thing through matrix product, not sure if there would be any difference in performance:

```
output = tf.squeeze(tf.expand_dims(weights, 1) @ embeddings, 1)
```

You could also just multiply and reduce, although that would in principle have worse performance due to having an intermediate tensor.

```
output = tf.reduce_sum(tf.expand_dims(weights, 2) * embeddings, axis=1)
```